# bundles - how to remove price from associated products in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, price, template, bundled-product

I have Bundle product, with fixed price. but when I add it to the cart it shows 0.00 or price for individual items associated in bundle below product.
http://prntscr.com/clt0em

How to removce those individual prices and leave only main price for bundle.
Additional problem is that those prices are without tax, so customer is confused. I would like to remove them completely, which file to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php and modify the funtion getBundleOptions

```
    <helpers>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_configuration>NameSpace_ModuleName_Helper_Bundle_Catalog_Product_Configuration</catalog_product_configuration>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
    </helpers>
```

Add helper file in the module

NameSpace_ModuleName_Helper_Bundle_Catalog_Product_Configuration extends Mage_Bundle_Helper_Catalog_Product_Configuration {

```
public function getBundleOptions (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface $item)
{
    $options = array();
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    /**
     * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
     */
    $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

    // get bundle options
    $optionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');
    $bundleOptionsIds = $optionsQuoteItemOption ? unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()) : array();
    if ($bundleOptionsIds) {
        /**
        * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Option_Collection
        */
        $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleOptionsIds, $product);

        // get and add bundle selections collection
        $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

        $bundleSelectionIds = unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

        if (!empty($bundleSelectionIds)) {
            $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds(
                unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()),
                $product
            );

            $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);
            foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
                if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {
                    $option = array(
                        'label' => $bundleOption->getTitle(),
                        'value' => array()
                    );

                    $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                    foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                        $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                        if ($qty) {
                            $option['value'][] = $qty . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName());
                        }
                    }

                    if ($option['value']) {
                        $options[] = $option;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $options;
}
```

}